# Is there an ADO.NET 2.0 driver for the ESRI file geodatabase?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

I am trying to make a connection to a file geodatabase to issue some SQL queries.

I don't need any spatial functionality, we're just trying to get data out of tables.  The application making the queries can use ADO.NET 2.0 drivers, which implement the `DbProviderFactory` classes to connect to various database and data sources.

I have found this: https://filegdbdotnet.codeplex.com/ but it's ADO 1.1 and doesn't implement the factory classes.

There's an Ole DB provider (`ESRI.GeoDB.OleDB.1`) but I think that requires an ESRI license to activate.  I'd like to avoid using that if possible since we can't be sure that the target machine running the application will have that.

Is there an ADO 2.0 driver for the file geodatabase?

Comment: do you have fme by chance?

Comment: No, we don't have FME.  The connection is being made from .NET.

Comment: gdal has the FileGDBDriver which is read only, but not .net http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html